# Chaining system commands onto git commands

Tags: git, bash, shell, terminal, alias

I'm trying to chain system commands in bash onto my git commands.

For instance: `git commit -m cat commit_message.txt`.

I've noticed I use the exact same 4 commands repeatedly, and I'd like to create an alias that does:

`git add -A && git commit -m cat ~/my_project/commit_message.txt && git push origin dev && git push heroku-staging master`.

I like to keep a log of the changes I make to my app in my commit_message.txt file, and update it each time I make a change, so it'd be ideal if I could just read this log from the terminal every time I want to commit a change.

I am by no means a terminal wizard, so I'm hoping this is an easy solution that I haven't come across yet.  I've searched quite a bit, and haven't found a similar use.

Comment: `git commit -m "$(< commit_message.txt)"`

Comment: Duplicating the entire previous history in each commit seems a bit odd. Just use `git log --format="%b"` if you want to see all changes up to and including the current commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git commit` has a `-F` (`--file`) that does exactly what you want, without using any shell magic: just use `git commit -F commit_message.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that :-)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need command substitution for using output from one command as an argument for another:

```
git commit -m "$(< commit_message.txt)"
```

You can also use `git commit -a` to add all files so no need to call `git add`:

```
git commit -am "$(< commit_message.txt)"
```

I would create a function for it:

```
do_git_stuff() {
  # Du stuff...
  : # The colon is here because a function cannot be empty. This can be removed when you
    # add some "real" code
}
```

To tie it together:

```
do_git_stuff() {
  git commit -am "$(< commit_message.txt)" \
    && git push origin dev \
    && git push heroku-staging master
}
```

What is `"$(< file.txt)"`?

The `<` operator means that you should take stdin from `file.txt`. A command substitution (`$(...)`) will return what is written to stdout. The quotes are used to avoid word splitting.

Comment: Fantastic!  I knew none of this, and I greatly appreciate the detailed explanation :)

Comment: @Doug Please see how Matthieu Moy suggest to use `git commit -F <file>`

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a script.

Create `$HOME/bin` directory for your executables:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
```

Add the directory to `$PATH` within your `~/.bashrc`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Update the environment in the current terminal session:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Create the script:

```
git_commit_file="$HOME/bin/git-commit"
cat > "$git_commit_file" <<'EOS'
#!/bin/bash -
message_file="$1"
# Add your commands here ...
EOS
chmod +x $git_commit_file
```

Now you can run `git-commit message.txt`.

By the way, creating aliases is as simple as adding an `alias name=command` in `~/.bashrc`, e.g.:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

But I'd recommend writing a script.

Answer (score 0):

to create a system alias you can do :

```
alias myName=myCommand
```

or if you want only a session alias (only available during your terminal alive) you can do :

```
myName=myCommand
```

To launch it you can do `$myName`

then to launch several command you can try to use pipe :

```
command 1 | command 2 ...
```

Comment: yes and no
it will depend if we want to rewrite all the system launching or only do a quick custom command alias
if you do test='apt-get moo' in a bash terminal it will play the correct 
command if you try $test

Comment: That's not alias, and I said it's wrong because there is no such thing as `myName = myCommand`, You at least need to remove the spaces.

Comment: @jeremy-denis `a=b` will assing the value `b` to the variable `a`

Comment: yes you are right but what is a command if it's not a string.
if you assign a command as a string to a variable b you will be abble to play it in your bash by doing $b